# cluster event message called multiple times

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing

Regarding to the following code, the application should fork 4 workers at each connection, then every worker send a message and disconnect.

However, after the first connection, `cluster.on('message')` received message incrementally.

```
const express = require('express');
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  const app = express();
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    [1, 2, 3, 4].map(() => cluster.fork());

    const count = [];
    cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {
      console.log({
        worker: worker.id,
        message
      });
      count.push(true);
      if (count.length === 4)
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    });
  });
  app.listen(8000, () => console.log('listening on 8000'));
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  process.send('msg');
  process.disconnect();
}
```

first output :

```
> curl localhost:8000
> { worker: 4, message: 'msg' }
> { worker: 1, message: 'msg' }
> { worker: 2, message: 'msg' }
> { worker: 3, message: 'msg' }
```

then

```
> curl localhost:8000
{ worker: 5, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 5, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 8, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 8, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 7, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 7, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 6, message: 'msg' }
{ worker: 6, message: 'msg' }
```

and so on...

I can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue stems from the way you use .on("message", ...). You are actually registering the listener every time your server gets called.

Moving the 'push to count' part of the listener out of the API call fixes this issue:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  let count = [];
  cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {
    console.log({
      worker: worker.id,
      message
    });
    count.push(true);
  });

  const app = express();
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(() => cluster.fork());

    let msgHandler = (worker, message) => {
      if (count.length === 4) {
        cluster.removeListener('message', msgHandler); // Do not forget to remove this event listener, or the issue will arise again!
        count.length = 0;
        return res.sendStatus(200);
      }
    };

    cluster.on('message', msgHandler);
  });
  app.listen(10101, () => console.log('listening on 10101'));
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  process.send('msg');
  process.disconnect();
}
```